Kafka installation: The system cannot find the path specified while starting the zookeeper
I have downloaded the kafka from the official website. I have extracted the kafka zip file in the following directory "C:\kafka" when I try to start the zookeeper with the command bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties it is giving me " The system cannot find the path specified"
I tried everything, watched various videos but it works fine for them, I have also followed the instructions step by step, but it is not working at all


your Java installation cannot have spaces in the path 2) Kafka doesn't require Zookeeper anymore

